# How to submit one of the dynamically generated forms (generated by php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

**PHP CODE**

```
echo '
  <div class = "card locations userNameContainer">
    <div class = "row" style = "padding: 0 !important;">
      <div class = "userName col s5" style = "display: inline-block;">
        '.$name.'
      </div>    

      <form class = "setPrivilegeForm col s6" id = "setPrivilegeForm">
        <input type="hidden" value='.$userID.' name="userID" > </input> 
        <select name="userType" id = "userType" class = "customSelect" onchange = "ajaxPrivilegeSubmit()">                          
          <option value="" disabled selected class = "grey-text">'.$typeText.'</option>
          <option value="1">Administrator</option>
          <option value="2" >Operator</option>
          <option value="3">Patron</option>                          
        </select>
      </form>

      <i class = "material-icons col s1">delete</i>
    </div>
  </div>

';
```

**Preview image of generated list of forms:**[image: preview]

**Script:**

```
function ajaxPrivilegeSubmit(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "setPrivilegeForm.php",
      data: $('#setPrivilegeForm').serialize(),

      success: function(data){

        $(".userNameList").html();
        Materialize.toast('Hello', 4000);

      }
  });

  //$('this').closest('.setPrivilegeForm').submit();
}
```

I want to be able to submit the form (each list item is a form) when the **value of the dropdown present in that form changes** but, currently only the first form is being submitted instead of the form whose dropdown was selected (*yes i know the reason why*).

Could someone guide me so as how to use some unique identifier which would help in submitting that form whose `<select>` value has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your form an id like 'setPrivilegeForm_1' and your select the id '1'. On the next one 'setPrivilegeForm_2' and '2' etc. Change your onchange function to ajaxPrivilegeSubmit(this.id) and change the actual function to

```
function ajaxPrivilegeSubmit(num){
  $.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "setPrivilegeForm.php",
  data: $('#setPrivilegeForm_'+num).serialize(),

  success: function(data){
     $(".userNameList").html();
     Materialize.toast('Hello', 4000);
   }
 });

 //$('this').closest('.setPrivilegeForm_'+num).submit();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thought i was missing something! Didn't think of passing the identifier as a parameter. I'll accept your answer :D Just format your code for proper viewing. Thanks mate! Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the same `id` attribute for multiple elements, what makes your HTML invalid.

If you don't use `id` attributes elsewhere, remove them and use `class` selector instead.
Then set [**`.change()`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler on your selects:

```
<form class = "setPrivilegeForm col s6">
   <input type="hidden" value='.$userID.' name="userID" > </input> 
   <select name="userType" class = "customSelect">                          
     <option value="" disabled selected class = "grey-text">'.$typeText.'</option>
     <option value="1">Administrator</option>
     <option value="2" >Operator</option>
     <option value="3">Patron</option>                          
   </select>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('.customSelect').change(function(){
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.ajax({
      type    : "post",
      url     : "setPrivilegeForm.php",
      data    : form.serialize(),
      success : function(data){
        $(".userNameList").html('');
        Materialize.toast('Hello', 4000);   
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes i was aware that i had the same id for all the generated forms. I couldn't seem to figure out how to use the unique identifier to select the appropriate form. Now the problem is solved :D Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

use serializeArray() instead of serialize();

Comment: I just wanted to submit a single form not all the forms.